# Convert yaw and pitch to relative mouse movement

Tags: c#, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

I have the output of a sensor fusion(Razor_AHRS) (gyro, magnetometer, accelerometer) as yaw pitch roll.

My goal is to convert them into mouse movements for yaw and pitch.

Unfortunately, Yaw goes from 0 to 359, pitch from 0 to 179(if you use offsets). So at some point there is a discontinuity.

What is the best way to convert these yaw and pitch values into something I could use with a relative mouse move method? So I need relative movement as int for x and y.

Comment: No discontinuity there.  If yaw goes 0 to 360 then pitch 180 to 360 is redundant. [Quick Google Search Reference](http://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates)

Comment: @FelixCastor Yaw goes from 0 ... 359, 0 ... 359 if rotated in the same direction continuously. Same with pitch. 359, 0 and 179, 0 are discontinuities.

Comment: No, if I put yaw -> 25 and pitch -> 190  that is the same as (which is non unique ) yaw -> 205 and pitch -> 170.

Comment: @FelixCastor Are you sure that you understand the question?